# Windows 10, RTX 2070]: Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, nvidia

I am currently trying to use a deep learning algorithm published last year (https://github.com/talmo/leap) to analyze the behavior of mice. So far I have used a Quadro P400 and it worked fine with CUDA 9.0. However, I bought a RTX 2070 because I needed much more computing power.
Because RTX cards are only compatible with CUDA 10.0 I have tried to perform a neew installation (the computer is not the same as before, it's a brand new one), but I have had this issue for some days now I couldn't so far find a workaround. I have tried different solutions as the ones mentioned here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828. I have also tried to compile myself tensorflow by following https://www.pytorials.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-10-0-for-python-on-windows/ and it worked, but I got the same error trying to run the algorithm.

#### System information

```
OS Platform and Distribution : Windows 10 Pro
TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): Source and Binary (tried both)
TensorFlow version: 1.12
Python version: 3.6.6
Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: pip and conda (tried both)
Bazel version (if compiling from source): 0.16.1
CUDA/cuDNN version: Cudnn - 7.4.2 , CUDA- 10.0
GPU model and memory: GeForce RTX 2070
```

I have tried different  versions of Cdunn, basically all the versions for cuda 10.0, other versions of Python (3.7.1, 3.6.4) and Tensorflow (1.13.1, nightly builds).

I don't know what I could try next so I am requesting your help.

Provide the exact sequence of commands / steps that you executed before running into the problem

Any other info / logs

Total params: 592,066
Trainable params: 592,066
Non-trainable params: 0

---

```
Created folder: C:\Users\dieudon\Downloads\models\190512_222333-n=17 
Epoch 1/15 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1334, in _do_call 
    return fn(*args) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn 
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun 
    run_metadata) 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. 
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter"], data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]] 
     [[{{node loss/mul/_287}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1575_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]] 
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Desktop\Matlab\leap-master\leap\training.py", line 276, in <module> 
    clize.run(train) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sigtools\modifiers.py", line 158, in __call__ 
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clize\runner.py", line 360, in run 
    ret = cli(*args) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clize\runner.py", line 220, in __call__ 
    return func(*posargs, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Desktop\Matlab\leap-master\leap\training.py", line 255, in train 
    viz_grid_callback 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper 
    return func(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2230, in fit_generator 
    class_weight=class_weight) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1883, in train_on_batch 
    outputs = self.train_function(ins) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2482, in __call__ 
    **self.session_kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run 
    run_metadata_ptr) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _run 
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1328, in _do_run 
    run_metadata) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1348, in _do_call 
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) 
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. 
     [[node conv2d_1/convolution (defined at C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3341)  = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter"], data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]] 
     [[{{node loss/mul/_287}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1575_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]] 
 
Caused by op 'conv2d_1/convolution', defined at: 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Desktop\Matlab\leap-master\leap\training.py", line 276, in <module> 
    clize.run(train) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sigtools\modifiers.py", line 158, in __call__ 
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clize\runner.py", line 360, in run 
    ret = cli(*args) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clize\runner.py", line 220, in __call__ 
    return func(*posargs, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Desktop\Matlab\leap-master\leap\training.py", line 191, in train 
    model = create_model(net_name, img_size, num_output_channels, filters=filters, amsgrad=amsgrad, upsampling_layers=upsampling_layers, summary=True) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Desktop\Matlab\leap-master\leap\training.py", line 104, in create_model 
    return compile_model(img_size, output_channels, **kwargs) 
  File "c:\users\dieudon\desktop\matlab\leap-master\leap\models.py", line 23, in leap_cnn 
    x1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu")(x_in) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 619, in __call__ 
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 168, in call 
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3341, in conv2d 
    data_format=tf_data_format) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 780, in convolution 
    return op(input, filter) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 868, in __call__ 
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 520, in __call__ 
    return self.call(inp, filter) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 204, in __call__ 
    name=self.name) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 1044, in conv2d 
    data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper 
    op_def=op_def) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func 
    return func(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op 
    op_def=op_def) 
  File "C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__ 
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack() 
 
UnknownError (see above for traceback): Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above. 
     [[node conv2d_1/convolution (defined at C:\Users\dieudon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3341)  = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter"], data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer, conv2d_1/kernel/read)]] 
     [[{{node loss/mul/_287}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1575_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is adding the following lines in the beginning of your code:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```